# How to get estimote beacons range in Android?

Tags: android, estimote

Suppose, I've 3 beacons in a room. When a person entered into that room. The Android App finds out those 3 beacons with different ranges like **1st** beacon is in **Immadiate** range, **2nd** beacon is in **near** range and **3rd** beacon is in **Far** range.

1. So, **how** can we find out the distances of those 3 (i.e in Meters or Feets) ?
2. And, **Which** beacons Content will get in App? (1 - Immadiate or 2 - Near or 3 - Far).

Comment: check estimote SDK and samples

Comment: Now, I'm getting 3 beacons UUID, Major, Minor, RSSI values. After that, suppose i want to get the content related to Beacon 1. Is it provide by default content of that or else we've to write logic for getting perticular beacons content.

Comment: there's no content for beacon at all. you get the id and you do what you want with that information. beacon gives you just id. nothing more

Comment: @Marcin Orloski!! Thanking you. based on that id how can we get the product information to display on App. Here, I'm confusing the link between id and the product information. Can you clear this in detail

Comment: how you connect id of beacon with product or group of products (or anything else) is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can check in samples

```
public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons)
            {
    // Note that beacons reported here are already sorted by
    // estimated
    // distance between device and beacon.
}
```

So For your point 2

> And, Which beacons Content will get in App? (1 - Immadiate or 2 - Near
>   or 3 - Far).

Yes those discovered beacons are sorted according to distance by estimote sdk

For your point 1

> So, how can we find out the distances of those 3 (i.e in Meters or Feets) ?

You need to check the SDK samples for that I just want to tell you that yes it is possible as Estimote Sample app shows the distance between beacon and device

> Note that here you will still get the estimated distance

:)

Comment: Thanking you for commenting, Initially i'm very confusing thats why all these similar questions. And i already got the solution for these.

Comment: YOur welcome, yes I can see that :) Where did you get all your answers, please share that and mark it as answer so that it will help others :)